# How to return a queryset from unrelated models that share fields with methods

Tags: python, django

I have users submit a form with information about their Household to view the total Household Rates on various Plans. Each Plan has a different Rate for each Person based on 'age' and the Household 'area'. Person is a ForeignKey to Household, but they are not related to Rate or Plan. However, the Rate model shares the 'age' and 'area' fields with methods in the Person and Household models.

I have a working python solution ([see that view here](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/jbHpoHQyYaNltRNflRWF/)), but I'm trying to use Django querysets so I have access to all of the fields with dot notation in my template. I've read the queryset docs extensively, but I can't figure out how to use them with my models because the Rate and Plan models are not related to Person or Household. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**Before trying to Sum, it would look like this:**

```
Example Household has 3 Persons:
Plan A:
    Rates:
        Person 1: $1
        Person 2: $2
        Person 3: $3
Plan B:
    Rates:
        Person 1: $2
        Person 2: $4
        Person 3: $6
```

**But I need template to return a Household Sum like this:**

```
Total for Household:
    Plan A: $6
    Plan B: $12
```

**models.py**

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_details = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Rate(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    premium = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

class Household(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County)
    effective_date = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=EFFECTIVE, default='2017-08-01')

    def area(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(county=self.county).first()

class Person(models.Model): 
    birthdate = models.DateField(max_length=25)
    household = models.ForeignKey(Household)

    @property
    def _age(self):
    """
    Returns the age from the date of birth
    """
        effective_string = self.household.effective_date
        effective_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(effective_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
        return effective_date_obj.year - self.birthdate.year - ((effective_date_obj.month, effective_date_obj.day) < (self.birthdate.month, self.birthdate.day))

class Area(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
```

Comment: You can write the functions you need inside the model and access them on template like a field.

Comment: the R in RDBMS stands for Relational. You probably don't have the right relations